# Megaupload download speed inconsistency

Tags: download, speed

When I start downloading a file the rate is 101kbps.
2 hours later it's 25.1 kbps.
Why is it slowing down and reducing the download rate?

Comment: **This question is not computer related**. It is only about the way another site works, and no one is really able to give an answer besides people from the site itself. Please review the FAQ to learn more about SuperUser (http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the 'free download' at MegaUpload (and other one-click hosting services) they reserve the right to adjust (reduce) the bandwidth in favor of their paid customers.

Comment: the moronic anonymous downvoter on the loose again? ^^

Comment: @Molly If it is a regular problem please flag it and I will follow up.

Comment: how do you 'flag' a downvote? someone just came along and downvoted Wil's and my answer for no good reason.

Comment: @Molly: I think you would flag the question with describing the problem (in the short space available), if it's obviously linked to the whole question here, or only your own answer, in case of a serial downvote, with an appropriate description too.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, bandwidth can be quite expensive - but what isn't used just goes to waste which is why they offer a free service.

[From their FAQ](http://www.megaupload.com/?c=faq)

> ### What is the advantage of a Megaupload Premium account?
>
> You get a lot of extra features for a very low flat fee - starting at EUR 9.99 per month: Highest download priority and bandwidth, unlimited downloading (no daily limits, no more annoying "Download limit exceeded" messages), no waiting before a download starts, direct downloads, access to files larger than 1024 megabyes, unlimited lifetime of the files in your account throughout the validity period of your premium status, dramatically increased capacity of your file portfolio, and many more.

As you are probably aware, if you do multiple downloads, your speed gets split/shared between them all. When you stop a download or it just finishes, the others (usually) go a bit faster. The same happens their end, they have (I am guessing) thousands of downloads going at any one moment and your speed will adjust to whatever is spare at any moment.